# Issue with $http service in Angular 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started using Angular 1.2.0 in my development app, and I noticed that the following function doesn't work anymore, take a look:

```
var myItems = angular.model('myItems', []);

myItems.controller('itemsController', function($scope, $http) {

    // delete item from the database
    $scope.deleteItem = function(id) {
        $http.delete('/api/items/' + id)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.items = data;
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                // log error 
            });
    };
});
```

Then in my view, this is what triggers deleting an item:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-click="deleteItem(item._id)"> {{ item.text }}
```

I'm very fresh to Angular, so I'm not sure what's exactly going wrong here, and a look at the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) file for version 1.2 on the Angular repository didn't yield an answer. Can somebody with more experience in Angular please explain to me what exactly the problem is here?

**Edit**: here's the log from the Chrome error console, which is visible as soon as the page is loaded. Clicking the checkbox to delete an item does nothing.

```
Error: [$parse:isecprv] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$parse/isecprv?p0=deleteItem(item._id)
at Error (<anonymous>)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:6:453
at ha (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:84:103)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:87:372
at Array.forEach (native)
at q (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:7:261)
at rc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:87:354)
at Jb.readIdent (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:149:31)
at Jb.lex (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:144:199)
at Ya.parse (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:151:12) <input type="checkbox" data-ng-click="deleteItem(item._id)">
```

**Update**: It turns out that one of the breaking changes in **Angular 1.2.0-rc2** (currently latest stable build) is the introduction of private properties on the scope chain. This potentially breaks a lot of apps that stores data in document-oriented databases such as, in my case `MongoDB`. If you're someone facing this same issue, you can either go back to version **1.2.0-rc3** (Google CDN [here](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js)) for now or wrap your sensitive APIs in a closure/controller as suggested in the changelog.

Comment: what do you see in network tab in chrome

Comment: Using `delete` in the dot notation will cause problems in IE8. Consider using `$http['delete'](...)`.

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal just updated the OP with the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Try changing the field name* (**_id**) . This error is clear from the error console.

From Angular version **1.2**

> Referencing private fields in Angular expressions is disallowed!
>   Expression: deleteItem(item._id)

Fields with names that begin or end with an underscore are considered private fields. Angular expressions are not allowed to reference such fields on the scope chain.

More [info](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24parse%3aisecprv?p0=deleteItem%28item._id%29)

Comment: Thank you. I've added a paragraph in the OP that might help someone else facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In error console first link points to the page

[http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse:isecprv?p0=deleteItem(item._id)](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24parse%3aisecprv?p0=deleteItem%28item._id%29)

This page explains that the error is that you use private property in expression.

The expression is `deleteItem(item._id)`.

`_id` - is a private property of item.